# javascript toggle to show/hide div

Tags: javascript, animation, html

I have a javascript toggle function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggle(layer) {
    var d = document.getElementById(layer);
    d.style.display = (d.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
    }
    </script>
```

What this does is:

I have a few links on page and on click of these links it shows / hides the respective DIV section associated with it..

In the following two links it opens and closes div section named stusearch & facsearch

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('stusearch')" ><b>Student Manager</b></a>
<a href="javascript:toggle('facsearch')" ><b>Faculty Manager</b></a>
```

This works well except that, i would like to hide the previous shown toggle when a new toggle link is clicked, at the moment the previous one remains open, and the new one opens up below it.

Comment: Are you opposed to using a js library such as jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked your code a bit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PPhqQ/1/).  I ended up adding a variable to store the divs you want to show/hide in case you want to add more divs to toggle:

```
var divs = [ "stusearch", "facsearch" ];
function toggle(layer) {
    var d
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
        d = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    d = document.getElementById(layer);
    d.style.display = '';
}
```

Comment: Instead of having to update the variable `divs` every time you add a new 'toggle-able' div, you could also add a class to each, e.g., `toggleSearch`, and change `var divs = $('.toggleSearch')`;

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle(layer) {
var d = document.getElementById(layer);
d.style.visibility = (d.style.visibility == 'hidden') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript, the easiest way is going to be to just 'remember' the last element you modified - aka:

```
var lastElement = null;

function toggle(elementId)
{
    if(lastElement != null)
        lastElement.style.display = 'none';

    var newElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

    newElement.style.display = (newElement.style.display == 'none') ? 'visible' : 'none';

    if(newElement != lastElement)
       lastElement = newElement;
}
```

You hide the last reference, then get the new one and show it.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a local var to it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function(){ 
   var shown;
   window.toggle = function(layer) {
     if(shown)
        shown.style.display = '';
     var d = document.getElementById(layer);
     d.style.display = (d.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
     shown = d;
   }
  }
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could control the visibility with a css class and do a blanket removel of the class from all elements before setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution in case you ever decide to implement a library:

**the JavaScript:**

```
function toggle(layer) {
    $('.toggleableSearch').hide();
    $(layer).show();
}
```

**the html:**

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('stusearch')" ><b>Student Manager</b></a>
<a href="javascript:toggle('facsearch')" ><b>Faculty Manager</b></a>

<div id="stusearch" class="toggleableSearch"></div>
<div id="facsearch" class="toggleableSearch"></div>
```